# Resize iframe height from external domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, iframe-resizer

On this page http://test.atelier47.fr/iframe-resizer/example/ I use the `iframe` `resizer` from https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer but the height is not setting, there is a problem ?

Comment: Please show the relavant code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change This

```
<iframe width="100%" id="iFrameResizer0" src="http://ifr.123devis.com/formulaires/act299_demande_de_devis_monte_charges.htm?affiliate=webatelier&amp;KWID=1010163328" style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%; position: absolute;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

To This

```
<iframe id="iFrameResizer0" src="http://ifr.123devis.com/formulaires/act299_demande_de_devis_monte_charges.htm?affiliate=webatelier&amp;KWID=1010163328" style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%;width: 100%; position: absolute;" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: ok remove position absolute and add min-height to iframe the bootstrap make it hard to maintain